# Solve the recurrence relation: $T(n) = T(n - \sqrt{\mathstrut n}) + T(\sqrt{\mathstrut n}) + O(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science

I think that $T(\sqrt{\mathstrut n})$ part is $O(log(log(n)))$ but I cannot solve the whole problem. . Can anyone help?

Edit:
The formula appears while solving the following problem:

If in quick-sort algorithm we choose the median of first $2\sqrt{\mathstrut n} + 1$ elements as the pivot element, what would be the time complexity of quick-sort in this case?

Answering the question we see every time the problem is divided into two sub-problems, first of size $\sqrt{\mathstrut n}$ and the other of size $n - \sqrt{\mathstrut n}$. So the recursive formula is as mentioned in the title.

Comment: Why can't $T(n) = 0$ for all $n$. Or $T(n) = n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @mathworker21 what do you mean? Note that we know n is greater than or equal to 1, so $T(n)$ can't be equal to zero.

Comment: what conditions do you have on $T(n)$? All I see is that $T(n) = T(n-\sqrt{n})+T(\sqrt{n})+O(n)$.

Comment: As it stands, any $T(n)=O(n)$ will satisfy the relation. It will even be satisfied for any $T(n)=an^u$ for $u\le3/2$. The $O(n)$ simply gives too much flexibility to lock down $T(n)$. You should also state where the problem comes from, and if there are any restrictions on $T$ (positive, increasing, ...?).

Comment: @EinarRødland I edited my question and added some details.

Comment: So, it is the worst case run time of a modified quicksort. First thing, I think finding the median will take time $T(2\sqrt{n}+1)$, which is longer than sorting the smaller set of $\sqrt{n}$ elements. But either way, I suspect the solution will be $T(n)\sim an\,\ln n$.

Comment: Actually, if instead of $O(n)$ you add $n$ (or $n-\sqrt{n}$) to represent one quicksort round, ie splitting the $n$ elements into those below and above the median, it seems $T(n)$ will be of order $n^{3/2}$.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/137028/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $T(n)$ is defined for all real $n\ge 1$ and $T(n)\le T(n-\sqrt{n})+ T(\sqrt{n})+Cn$ for some $C>0$ and all $n\ge 4$. We claim that a function $T(n)=\frac 23C n^{3/2}+D$,  where $D\ge 0$. For this it suffices to remark that, by Lagrange’s Theorem, there exists $c\in (n-\sqrt{n},n)$ such that $$T(n)- T(n-\sqrt{n})=T’(c)\sqrt{n}\le Cc^{1/2}\sqrt{n}=Cn.$$